# How to concat MTS videos and apply filters without re-encoding using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, fadein, fadeout, re-encoding

I have a txt file with many MTS video files. I want to merge them all together using **FFmpeg** and get one big MTS file. But I want to apply **fade-in** and **fade-out** to the final video. Can I do it without re-encoding? Because re-encoding takes a lot of time, but I need to do it fast.

**Edit**

Here is the output when I run

```
ffmpeg -i C:/Users/aleks/Downloads/IMPORTANT/MTS_videos/my.MTS
```

Output:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'C:/Users/aleks/Downloads/IMPORTANT/MTS_videos/my.MTS':
  Duration: 00:00:08.51, start: 1.433367, bitrate: 5275 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 120k tbc
```

**Edit 2**

ok, I think I figured it out. The problem was in audio codec, I added `-c:a mp3` and it seems to be working. However now I have the second problem. I have 3 videos. I apply fade in to the first one, fade out to the third one and nothing to the second one. I get them from one video by slicing using this command 3 times

```
ffmpeg -i 'C:/Users/aleks/Downloads/video.MTS' -ss 20 -t 5 -c copy 'C:/Users/aleks/Downloads/third.MTS'
```

But when I run it my video is 2 seconds long (it must be 5 seconds long). Can you help me with fixing this problem.

PS. i have seen similar question and there was a suggestion to add `-async 1`. It didn't help. And moving `-t 5` to the position before `-i` didn't help as well.

**Also** if I **delete** `-c copy` everything works **fine**. But I need to **keep** it because I **don't want to re-encode**.

Comment: No. You have to re-encode all videos where the frame contents are changed.

Comment: @Gyan ok, thank you

Comment: @llogan thank you for the reply, I edited my question and added the output of `ffmpeg -i input.MTS`. I hope this is what you need